# How can I use the same script for multiple sheets on a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to create a script for multiple dependable drop-downs on google sheets. When I apply the script it only applies to the sheet Twitter (see below). I have other sheets titled Facebook, Instagram and LinkedIn.

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Twitter");
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tags");
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
var firstLevelColumn = 5;
var secondLevelColumn = 6;
var thirdLevelColumn = 7;
var fourthLevelColumn = 8;

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "Twitter" && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 1){
    applyfirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  } else if (wsName == "Twitter" && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 1){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
  }else if (wsName == "Twitter" && c === thirdLevelColumn && r > 1)
    applyThirdLevelValidation(val,r);
  


} //end onEdit

function applyfirstLevelValidation(val,r){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(t){ return t[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(t){ return t[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    } 
  
}

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(t){ return t[0] === firstLevelColValue && t[1] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(t){ return t[2] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    } 
  
}

function applyThirdLevelValidation(val,r){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
      var secondLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(t){ return t[0] === firstLevelColValue && t[1] === secondLevelColValue && t[2] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(t){ return t[3] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    } 
  
}




function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can use this technique:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = ["Sheet1","Sheet2"];
  const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName())
  if(~idx);// this is the same as comparing your sheet name with a string only in this case you are asking if it's one of the strings in names.
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)